# Compare two lists and overwrite/append from one to the other

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to compare two lists in python and overwrite partial matches from one to the other or add anything new. For example:

new_list:

```
Jason £420
Adam £205
Emma £670
Tim £900
Penny £120
Ed £470
```

old_list:

```
Jason £200
Adam £205
Alex £400
Emma £600
Penny £120
```

I'm trying to update items on old_list if they're different from new_list (e.g. Jason), add new items (e.g. Tim), and keep old items that aren't in new_list (e.g. Alex), getting something like this:

```
Jason £420
Adam £205
Alex £400
Emma £670
Penny £120
Tim £900
Ed £470
```

I've been trying to do this with for loops, but I think I'm getting stuck. Got this so far:

```
for x, y in enumerate(old_list):
        for z in new_list:
                if z.split(" ")[0] in y:
                        old_list[x] = z
                elif z.split(" ")[0] not in old_list:
                        old_list.append(z)
                else:
                        pass
```

Comment: Why not using `dict` for that?

Comment: "I think I'm getting stuck" is not an error destription. Try to describe what you want to do in human language first, then try to translate that into Python. If you have problems, ask specific questions.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `dict`, however if you need to keep the elements in the list ordered, you could use `OrderedDict` like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

old_d = OrderedDict({'John': 100, 'Marie': 200})
new_d = OrderedDict({'John': 100, 'Marie': 400})  # Marie changes here

# important part, update keys from old_d with values of new_d
# also adds new key-value from new_d
old_d.update(new_d)  # update keys 

print(old_d)  # OrderedDict([('John', 100), ('Marie', 400)])
your_final_list = old_d.items()
```

Answer (score 2):

Following up on *why* `dict` is the right answer here is checking the documentation of the `dict.update()` method: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update

> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, overwriting
>   existing keys.

This is exactly the behaviour you're looking for:

```
old_dict = {"Jason": 200, "Emma": 40}
new_dict = {"Tim": 10, "Jason": 420 }

old_dict.update( new_dict )
print old_dict
{"Jason": 420, "Emma": 40, "Tim": 10}
```

If you need access to the elements in a particular order then using a `sorted()` on `old_dict.keys()` gives you enough possibilities to implement any sorting needs you may have.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is much better to solve with `dict` but.. Solution with `list`, using `map`:

```
names_old = list(map(lambda x: x.split()[0], old_list))
names_new = list(map(lambda x: x.split()[0], new_list))

for x, y in enumerate(names_new):
    item = new_list[names_new.index(y)]
    if y in names_old:
        old_list[names_old.index(y)] = item
    else:
        old_list.append(item)

In [676]: old_list
Out[676]: 
['Jason £420',
 'Adam £205',
 'Alex £400',
 'Emma £670',
 'Penny £120',
 'Tim £900',
 'Ed £470']
```

Comment: FTR, list comprehensions are more pythonic `names_old = [x.split()[0] for x in old_list]`